# malloc Error in specific makefile

Tags: c++

I have a software, code of which I have modified and run make again.

If I run the modified code in a black QtCreator project it runs well (nothing specific to Qt, just an example), but if I compile with software's original makefile, I get error on a line as:

```
(*F)=(double**) malloc((size_arr)*sizeof(double*));
```

Not in compile time, but a segmentation fault at runtime. F is a ***double by the way.

What should I check in makefile? Any guess?

Comment: Can you post the code where `F` is declared and initialized?

Comment: I declare it as 
    double ***F;

Comment: Things to check: Is size_arr much bigger than you expect? That will cause some malloc implementations to crash. Does *F point to a valid memory location?

Comment: How did you initialize it? If you haven't initialized it, you can't dereference and write to it with `*F`; a pointer needs to point to something in order to dereference it.

Comment: @emk: malloc is never going to crash because you asked for too much memory. The worst that will happen is it will return NULL.

Comment: @Martin York: There's a lot of different malloc implementations out there, and I've observed that at least one of them segfaults if you accidentally try something like 'malloc(-1)' and wind up trying to allocate 0xFFFFFFFF bytes of memory. I'm not saying this is standards-compliant behavior.

Comment: @emk: Yes. There are lots of bugs in software. Standard says if you requet more than is available by the dynamic memory management system then you will get NULL. Write an e-mail to the provider of you stdlib with a test case to show the bug. It will be fixed in the next release (PS you were obviously not using a mean stream library as these are well tested for this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `F` is `NULL` or pointing to an invalid memory location. Since `F` gets dereferenced on the left side of the assignment, it needs to be properly initialized, so that it points to a memory location that can store the `double**` returned by malloc.

Comment: Oops, knew I should have turned my second comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code, I can't see anything wrong with that allocation *per se*. Be sure you've allocated space for F itself, and initialize all of the pointers in the block *F before dereferencing them.

Answer (score 0):

*F needs to  point to something before you use it.  Please check that it is not null and has a reasonable value.  If it is on the stack then check the address is a reasonable stack address. If it is pointing at something dynamic (returned by malloc) then then that it is a reasonable heap address.
Either use a debuger to print out F or use printf.  I know that printf is not real popular with a
lot of folks for debugging like this but you can print the address of something else on the stack
and something returned by malloc and see if F has a similar value.  Try `printf("%08x",F);`